# My $_SESSION don't work on my page why?

Tags: php, session

i am using `$session[login]` but `$_SESSION` seem like don't not work on my home page of `html/php` webpage . It don have show up anything . why? could anyone help me
and tell me why? is it the session name wrong? or need to input php inside?

```
<html>
<title>Home</title>
<head>
<link href="SSCdesign.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="script.js"> </script>
</head>

<body>

<header id="SSClogo"><img src="SSC_logo_v2.png"></header>
<div id='userbar'>
<?php

$_SESSION['login'] = true;                  
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $_SESSION['student_id'] = $row['studnet_id'];
    $_SESSION['student_name'] = $row['student_name'];
}
?>
</div>
<div id='wrapper' align="center"> 
   <nav id='cssmenu'>
   <ul>
   <li class='active'><a href='SSC.html'><span>Home</span></a></li>
   <li><a href='advisors.html'><span>Advisors</span></a></li>
   <li class='has-sub'><a href='pals.html'><span>PALS</span></a>
      <ul>
         <li><a href='registersession.html'><span>Register Session</span></a></li>
         <li><a href='timetable.html'><span>Timetable</span></a></li>
         <li><a href='feedback.html'><span>Feedback</span></a></li>
         <li class='last'><a href='buzz.html'><span>Buzz</span></a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li class='has-sub'><a href='econsultation.html'><span>e-Consultation</span></a>
      <ul>
         <li><a href='appointment.html'><span>e-Appointment</span></a></li>
         <li><a href='upcoming.html'><span>Upcoming List Appointment</span></a></li>
         <li class='last'><a href='history.html'><span>History</span></a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li class='has-sub'><a href='workshop.html'><span>Workshop</span></a>
      <ul>
         <li><a href='calendar.html'><span>Calendar</span></a></li>
         <li class='last'><a href='eportfolio.html'><span>e-Portfolio</span></a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href='facilities.html'><span>Facilities</span></a></li>
   <li class='last'><a href='contactus.html'><span>Contact Us</span></a></li>

   <li class='la'><a href='login.html'><span>Login</span></a></li>
</ul>

<div id="announcement">
    <h2> <center> Announcement will be posted here </center> </h2>
    &nbsp;
    <p> <center> This site is currently under development, do check it out soon! </center> </p>
</div>

<div id="slideshow">
    <h2> <center> Slideshow will be here </center> </h2>
</div>
    </nav>
    <div class="push"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you not loading `session_start();`? Plus, is your file indeed `.php`? All other links are `.html` - Your code suggests that there is a lot missing. You may have also made a typo for "studnet_id" in `$row['studnet_id']`.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything.

Comment: Why are you using `mysqli_` in your other question http://stackoverflow.com/q/27376754/ and `mysql_` here? If you're still using `mysqli_`, then you do know that those two APIs do **not** intermix. Another contributing factor as to why your code is failing.

Answer (score 3):

You have to start your session before you use it with:

```
session_start();
```

So your code should looks something like this:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['login'] = true;
```

(Also if you say you use: `$session[login]`, it's wrong you would have to use it with: `$session['login']` otherwise `login` is a constant which it isn't)

For more information see: http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

Comment: Have a look at OP's other question http://stackoverflow.com/q/27376754/ - Typo in code above for "studnet_id" then using `mysql_` function, whereas the other question is using `mysqli_`. Column name in other question is "studentid". So, this question is very very unclear. But I did +1 ;)

Comment: Well, given the time the OP posted the question with no feedback whatsoever since, I think the OP is confused and is probably trying to parse PHP into an `.html` file; not to mention the other comments I've left. All of these factors adding up to the contribution of code failure. Time will only tell at this point. Oh well, you've made a few points on this one. I am moving on, *cheers*

Comment: @Fred-ii- agree with you ;D (if it would be `.html` he would see the code) A few question i shouldn't write a answer! (Your comments under OP's question should help him!)

Comment: True. However, the rest of the links in OP's code are `.html` and is unclear whether OP is using `.php` for the file's extension or not. OP hasn't given us much more to *properly* diagnose the problem. The missing `session_start();` and mixing MySQL APIs are the two major pieces to the puzzle; oh, and the "studnet_id" row.